# Is there any way to suspend MemoryCache expiration for a certain period of time?

Tags: c#, .net, memorycache

I am using .NET's MemoryCache class to cache data within my application.  During most the application's use cases, the absolute and/or sliding expiration cache policies work great for my application.  However, at certain periods of time, the application may kick off a long running process which does not update any application data.  The process is typically so long that the cache will expire and scavenge the cached data during this process, which is when I really want the data to stick around in the cache.  Is there any way to suspend expiration and/or scavenging on the MemoryCache temporarily?

I could go throw all of my items and change the expiration policies one-by-one, but I'm afraid that given that I have hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of items in the cache, that wouldn't work from a performance perspective.

One thought would be to put the item back into the cache in the CacheEntryRemovedCallback, but that seems like you're fighting the system rather than working with it, and wouldn't be thread-safe.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit broad as it is, really. Without some specific code, all one could offer is very broad recommendations about using Cache; such as, don't try to 'force' it to hold onto things like this, and if you have so much stored in it, consider a different strategy.

Comment: What alternative strategy would you suggest?  As I said, MemoryCache is quite good at holding on to the large amount of items that I need, and works like a charm for 95% of my use cases.

Comment: Well, you are probably pushing it to its limits already. It's a *cache*; not a persistent memory store. You'd really need a much more focused question based on some specific code. It's not really possible to give you helpful, general advice on this.

Comment: My question was, can MemoryCache, or some alternative .Net cache, handle my use case?   I don't want a persistent memory store: that would quickly cause my application to run out of memory--I want a cache that evicts based on certain policies.  I just want my policies to be more dynamic based on the "mode" that the application is in...

Answer (score 0):

The Memcached or NCache are flat memory caching systems it support your expiration in similar way. It is your Data/Cache provider Lib has to have intelligence to repopulate it on expiry.

You can use InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration policy for MemoryCache but it will have it forever. Or Write your own Caching Lib.  MemoryCache Uses Timers for expiration check. You can have your know version do it for you with the extended logic.

Your custom policy extension object should have delegate to subscribe the Application process event to expire the items.

Good luck
-Srini